# Convertir Left Join SQL a Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

## ¿Cómo puedo convertir la siguiente consulta de SQL a Linq?

```
SELECT Facturas.IDFactura, SUM(MovimientosDineros.Valor) AS Totalaportado
FROM Facturas
JOIN MovimientosDineros ON Facturas.IDFactura = MovimientosDineros.IdFactura
GROUP BY Facturas.IDFactura
```

He intentado hacerlo así pero no logro terminarla:

```
var consulta = (from fac in db.Facturas
                join mov in db.MovimientosDineros on fac.IDFactura equals mov.IdFactura);
```

Nota: es importante que la consulta arroje todas las facturas, y haga la suma en la tabla `MovimientosDineros`. Es por este motivo que en SQL utilicé `Left Join`.

Comment: pero en la consulta sql no aplicas ningun LEFT JOIN, eso es un JOIN simple con un GROUP BY

Comment: tiene algun sentido en la consulta sql agrupar por id de factura? si este es la key de la tabla como que sera un secuencial y no agrupara nada

Answer (score 1):

No queda muy claro el por qué quieres hacer un left join. He supuesto que es porque hay facturas que simplemente no tienen movimientos asignados, por lo que el siguiente fragmento de código gira en torno a eso.

```
var q = from fac in db.Facturas
        join mov in db.MovimientosDineros
            on fac.IDFactura equals mov.IdFactura into facturasMovimientos // 1
        from facMov in facturasMovimientos.DefaultIfEmpty() // 2
        group facMov by fac into grupo // 3
        let sum = grupo.Sum(g => g == null ? 0 : g.Valor) // 4
        select new 
        {
            IDFactura = grupo.key.IDFactura,
            Totalaportado = sum
        };
```

Voy a explicar el código usando los números que he indicado en los comentarios:

- En 1 lo que se ha hecho es juntar las facturas con sus movimientos y se ha "englobado" esta unión en una tabla facturasMovimientos.
- En 2 especificamos que si una factura no tiene movimientos se devuelva un valor por defecto (null). Consultar la documentación de esta función si lo ve necesario.

> Resumen: Devuelve los elementos de la secuencia especificada o el
>   valor predeterminado del parámetro de tipo en una colección singleton si la > secuencia está vacía.

- En 3 agrupamos todas las filas de facturasMovimientos por facturas.
- En 4 se calcula la suma total especificando que si alguna fila es nula el sumando sea 0.

Explicado el código, tengo que decir que no lo he podido probar, por lo que si contiene algún error o mis conceptos son erróneos indíquenlo y lo corregiré, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser algo como

```
var cosnutla = from fac in db.Facturas
                join mov in db.MovimientosDineros on fac.IDFactura equals mov.IdFactura into g
                select new {
                    factura = fac,
                    Monto = g.Sum(x=>x.Valor)
                };
```

hay varias formas de realizar un left join, podrias solo agrupar por la union

[Perform grouped joins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

o ademas podrias aplicar condiciones

[Perform left outer joins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar algo así con expresiones lambda:

```
var q = Facturas.Select(x =>
            new {
                Id = x.IDFactura,
                Sum = MovimientosDineros.Where(y => y.IDFactura == x.IDFactura).Sum(z => z.Valor)
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Simplemente recorremos la tabla de Facturas y por cada una de ellas generaremos un nuevo objeto, el cual tendrá como Id el id de la tabla facturas y un campo llamado Sum, que contendrá la suma de todos los valores de la tabla MovimientosDinero que coincida con el Id.

Comment: sería útil que añadieras algún tipo de explicación sobre este código

Comment: Simplemente recorremos la tabla de Facturas y por cada una de ellas generaremos un nuevo objeto, el cual tendrá como Id el id de la tabla facturas y un campo llamado Sum, que contendrá la suma de todos los valores de la tabla MovimientosDinero que coincida con el Id

Answer (score 0):

y si creas una clase con decorador, llenas los objetos desde sql en una lista ( con tu inner join) y despues la lista la trabajas con linq ej:

```
 listado.sum(x => x.MovimientosDineros).Tolist();
```